# highstock x-label rotation bug

Tags: highcharts

With the version 2.0.1 of highstock i notice that there is a bug.

When I draw "Two panes, candlestick and volume" , in the second chart (column chart)
I put border color for the columns...
And I put a rotation in x-labels ...
But the bottom line of the columns isn't dranw ....
How can I revolve this problem ?
Thanks.

Here the fiddle (please do a zoom to see the column detail)

```
[example]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mabaes/94r3w/

Comment: Well, your demo works fine for me. Do I need to use some specific browser?

Comment: Here there is an image with a sort explanantion that i want [link]http://www.ales8enelreduit.com/highchart/bottom_line.png

Comment: Is that working fine for you: http://jsfiddle.net/94r3w/1/ ? Border is drawn below red line.

Comment: Yes! this is that i want.. but which value do you change? I can't see the difference bettween your code and my code ....

Comment: Ah, sorry. It's upcoming 4.0.2 version :)